Can a dependently typed language be Turing complete?
It seems as though dependently typed languages are often not Turing complete. Why can we not allow every function to have general recursion (which would make the language Turing complete), instead of only allowing a more restricted form of recursion?
Is something preventing creators of dependently typed languages from allowing all functions to be capable of general recursion?
For example:

Agda: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)#:~:text=Agda%20is%20a%20total%20language,possible%20to%20prove%20arbitrary%20statements
Coq: What are the practical limitations of a non-turing complete language like Coq?


I'm confused about the question: no programming languages are Turing complete. Which was rather Turing's (and Gödel's) point. Not just "often" but always. Then what are you asking specifically about dependently-typed languages?

@AntC "Turing complete" does not mean "can solve the halting problem."

@AntC huh? That's the exact opposite of the reality. Every programming language is Turing complete, as are a bunch of things that you need to squint really hard for to see that they can do computation.

Eek, thanks folks. Brain-o. I must be mixing up with "solve the halting problem".

I have worked on the wording of the question and title a bit. Does this still match the question that you want to ask? I have included a detail which I think was overlooked. This particular detail, I believe, is still leading to confusion. By making it explicit, we can address this question more effectively. Hope this helps and let me know if this does not match what you want to ask!

In case it doesn't get re-opened, here is an answer: There is something preventing many creators of dependently typed languages from making it Turing complete in an "obvious" way (by allowing general recursion everywhere). We can see a type system as corresponding to a kind of logic. From this perspective, we can write programs that correspond to proofs of theorems. But allowing every function to do general recursion leads to an inconsistent logic. However we can still get Turing completeness in a different way, by being a bit more careful. See @gallais answer for a nice overview of that.

What you have read is misinformation.
You can see for instance in IO.Base that the Agda standard library ships with a
combinator called forever that happily executes an IO action until
the end of times (or, more likely, the IO action eventually decides
to call either exitSuccess or exitFailure):
forever : IO {a} ⊤ → IO {a} ⊤

Of course you will not find a function fix : (A → A) → A but that is
because the type has to be honest about the possibility of non-termination
(just like types in Haskell have to be honest about the possibility of
mutation, or input-output, or failure). To encapsulate such effects you
typically use monads. Above we used the IO monad but there are other
monads capturing the idea of non-termination, cf. McBride's Turing-Completeness Totally Free

Wow. OK. This is a great answer--thanks. But why does it seem to be reported in various places that agda is not Turing complete? Where does this even come from?

This is where it is useful to consider Agda as a Turning-incomplete DSL that produces Turing-complete IO actions.

I feel like this has avoided the truth in a somewhat deceptive way. The motivation of using these languages as proof systems and the bad interaction of that idea with self-reference is completely lost.

I think the answer provides some useful information which is often lost, but at the same time I agree with @DanielWagner. Fully unrestricted general recursion leads to inconsistency when you consider the language as a logic. You have to carefully restrict it to avoid this.

@DanielWagner, could you please expand on this for me? Thank you :)

there's nothing deceptive about saying that the types have to be honest about non-termination. And it's not an arcane escape hatch either: using bisimulations you can prove the properties of these potentially non-terminating programs!
